# jQuery - If statement not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple if statement that isn't functioning - is the error in the syntax?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        var article = 'Running';

       if(article == 'Running') {
         $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#000');
         }
        else if(article) == 'Tennis') {
         $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#555');
         }
     });

 </script>
```

This line will be set dynamically later in development:

```
var article = 'Running';
```

(EDIT)
The problem was having two instances of :
    $(document).ready(function() {

on the page.

It was resolved by using:

```
    $(window).load(function(){


    var article = 'Baseball';


    if(article == 'Running') {
    $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#6e7783')

   }
```

Comment: Your code has no meaning. Even you don't wrap `article` in jq object, you just set it then check its value, `article` will always be equal to just what you set it

Comment: The first instace of 'Running' is set dynamically by another part of a template - 

`var article = 'Running';` actually reads more like: `var article = '{{dynamic-category-name}}}';`

It just outputs as 'Running' so that's what I want to check.

Comment: So that's making little more sense indeed...

Comment: article is simple variable you can't match its value using $(article) You should use like this " if(article == 'Running') "

Comment: I have amended the code above to include formatting suggestions, however it still doesn't function

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you want to achieve and wthat went wrong?

Comment: I am trying to dynamically register the category in which the current article appears. It's set dynamically, but outputs as: ('Running'). I want to then style some H1 titles based on the output of the current article category. 

So: if{current article title} is { Running } then make the h2 tags that have an article-title class { go white }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to use your declared variable so...

Change:

```
if($(article) == 'Running') {
    $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#000');
}
if($(article) == 'Tennis') {
    $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#555');
}
```

to:

```
if(article == 'Running') {
    $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#000');
}
else if(article == 'Tennis') {
    $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#555');
}
```

$(...) is the selector in JQuery and has nothing to do with your local variable.

Comment: `var article = 'Running';` in same function scope, so it will never be equal to `Tennis`

Comment: Yea you are right but we pretend that article gets changed in later development. For the moment its more or less like a placeholder I guess

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately no response - any clue why? Is it possible to force the <h1> tag that's being affected to take the style - like '!important' or something?

Comment: What do you mean with "no response"?

Comment: @LPK That's right - it will change later down the line.

Comment: The css attribute is not being taken onto the <h1> element. It's background remains it's default white.

Comment: Have you set the class of <h1> to article-title?

Comment: Yes. The h2 tag has .article-title, and has a background-color value set within that class too.

Comment: Show your h2 statement

Comment: `<h2 class="article-title">Baseball</h2>`

Comment: So your line $('.article-title').css('background-color', '#000'); not changing background?

Comment: Exactly. It's remaining as the defaulted Red / White colour as set in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Is there your class "article-title" used multiple time in your page?

Comment: try using this $('[class^="article-title"]').css('background-color', '#000'); in your if statement and let me know if it works(EDIT - use single quote for outside of selector)

Comment: Unfortunately not - 

Currently the code looks like this (i removed the else if for now) -  
    
   `$(document).ready(function() {
     var article = 'Running';
      
     if(article == 'Running') {
    $('[class^="article-title"]').css('background-color', '#000')
     }
    });` (EDIT - single quotes used - result is the same)

Comment: check above edit in my comment and try again(put my updated line)

Comment: have you check this line executing or not by putting debugger?

Comment: [http://berlinbraves.webflow.io/posts/cancerresearch] the code is at the bottom of the page if you want to see it live.

Comment: I have added 'debugger;' to the script, but no result.

Comment: If you run $('[class^="article-title"]').css('background-color', '#000') line in your browser console it is working. check whether your line executing or not

Comment: is your line executing?

Comment: Put debugger; in if statement and debug your code with internet explorer

Comment: I am using Chrome + Dev Tools, but past that, I have very little idea how to debug this.

Comment: which dev - tool you using?

Comment: you are using 2 $(document).ready function try putting your code in 1st ready fucntion and remove another one.

Comment: Is there another way of wrapping this code in something equivalent to '$(document).ready'? The first '$(document).ready' is general script for the whole site, and this code HAS to come from a specific page. Could I wrap this specific some in something like $(thisspecificpageID).ready ?

Comment: we need to write document.ready function for every page. you can try 1 possibility like make 1 new page -> put your code containing ' article-title ' in that page and in document ready of that page your if statement.

Comment: Hi there - I resolved it by placing the code inside an {on window load}. After that, I reverted back to the original jQuery css, and the colours are resolving perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: by the way you got it. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Here above article is a variable, For Javascript variable we don't need to use $(article), we can simply compare if(article=='Running') ..